# Read multiple sheets with differents 'read_csv_options'

Tags: python-polars

I have 2 sheets from the same excel that have different reading options. One way to read them is:

```
df1 = pl.read_excel(path, sheet_name='sheet1', read_csv_options={'skip_rows': 2})
df2 = pl.read_excel(path, sheet_name='sheet2', read_csv_options={'infer_schema_length': 2000})
```

However, as one could imagine, that is extremely inefficient, since I'm reading the same excel twice. **Is there a way to read the excel once then reading each sheet with their options?** I'm not used to lazy working, maybe some solution with lazy?

I also tried passing a list to 'read_csv_options',

```
pl.read_excel(
path, sheet_name=['Base', 'Data_Funds'], read_csv_options=[{'infer_schema_length': 2000}, {'skip_rows': 2}]
)
```

Comment: What makes you think that this is actually inefficient? I'd think that Excel files are sufficiently structured and polars sufficiently efficient to only read the relevant parts.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the read_excel isn't the best structured, because of the format .xlsx, so it has to read all the excel or most of it. As an example for you, one of these sheets is quite big, while the other is pretty small and the reading time for both of them is big: 1.74s vs 2.84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on linux or can install WSL, you can try [`fastexcel`](https://github.com/ToucanToco/fastexcel) which is an engine in [`read_excel`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_excel.html#polars.read_excel). They're working on [Windows support](https://github.com/ToucanToco/fastexcel/issues/154) so stay tuned for updates on that front.

You'll need to use `fastexcel` directly in order to do what you want rather than to just set the engine in `read_excel`

```
import fastexcel
wb = fastexcel.read_excel(path)
df1 = wb.load_sheet("sheet1", skip_rows=2).to_polars()
df2 = wb.load_sheet("sheet2").to_polars()
```

Unfortunately `fastexcel` doesn't offer a custom infer dtype parameter (yet) so your second sheet might end up with a bunch of nulls. When [this](https://github.com/ToucanToco/fastexcel/pull/164) gets merged then it should work as it will be the equivalent of setting `infer_scheme_length=inf`.

Alternatively, you could use `python-calamine` like this:

First you can load this function (a more complete version [here](https://gist.github.com/deanm0000/81512b119e26e2c4a5b235989653fec2)):

```
def plcal(wb, sheet, header_rows=1, header_merge_char="_", skip_rows=0):
    df = pl.from_records(wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet).to_python(), orient="row")[skip_rows:]
    df.columns = (
        pl.select(
            pl.Series(
                "colnames",
                [
                    header_merge_char.join([y for y in x if y != ""])
                    for x in zip(*[df.rows()[x] for x in range(header_rows)])
                ],
            )
        )
        .with_columns(count=pl.int_range(0, pl.len()).over("colnames"))
        .with_columns(
            colnames=pl.when(pl.col("count") > 0)
            .then(pl.col("colnames") + pl.lit("_") + pl.col("count").cast(pl.Utf8))
            .otherwise(pl.col("colnames"))
        )["colnames"]
    )
    df = df[header_rows:]
    for col_name in df.columns:
        for dtype in [pl.Int64, pl.Float64, pl.Date]:
            try:
                df = df.with_columns(pl.col(col_name).replace({"": None}).cast(dtype))
                continue
            except:
                pass
    return df
```

The `header_rows` and `header_merge_char` take care of instances where there are multiple rows that make up the header which, I find, is often the case in Excel files

then you can use it like this:

```
from python_calamine import CalamineWorkbook
wb = CalamineWorkbook(path)
df1 = plcal(wb, "sheet1", skip_rows=2)
df2 = plcal(wb, "sheet2")
```